# How do I align the matrix used in SpriteBatch and the matrix used in BasicEffect?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, geometry, effects

I'm writing a Windows tool that uses XNA and allows the user to place textures on the screen.

I'm using a 'camera' for the SpriteBatch used to draw the textures, e.g:

```
Matrix matrixForSpriteBatch = Matrix.CreateTranslation(
    -_cameraPosition.X, -_cameraPosition.Y, 0.0f) *
Matrix.CreateRotationZ(_rotation) *
Matrix.CreateScale(_scale) *
Matrix.CreateTranslation(
     GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, 
     GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2, 0.0f);
```

This is working fine - the user can drop a texture onto the canvas and move, rotate and size it. They can also move the camera around to see more things.

What I now want to do is let the users click around to define points of a polygon.  These points are then sent to my `DrawPolygonFilled` method:

```
public void DrawPolygonFilled( SpriteBatch spriteBatch, 
        Vector2[ ] worldPoints, 
        Color color )
{
    Matrix matrixForVertices =
        Matrix.CreateTranslation( _cameraPosition.X, -_cameraPosition.Y, 0.0f ) *
            Matrix.CreateRotationZ( -rotation ) *
                Matrix.CreateScale( camera.Scale ) ;


    Vector2[] transformedPoints = worldPoints.Transform( matrixForVertices ) ;

    var vertices = new VertexPositionColor[ transformedPoints.Length ] ;

    for (int i = 0; i < transformedPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        vertices[ i ] = new VertexPositionColor( new Vector3( transformedPoints[ i ], 0 ), color ) ;
    }

    Vector2[ ] outputVertices ;
    short[ ] outputIndicies ;
    Vertices.Triangulate( transformedPoints, Vertices.WindingOrder.Clockwise, out outputVertices, out outputIndicies ) ;

    if (outputIndicies.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach( EffectPass pass in _basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes )
        {
            pass.Apply( ) ;

            spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(
                Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.PrimitiveType.TriangleList,
                vertices,
                0,
                vertices.Length,
                outputIndicies,
                0,
                outputIndicies.Length /3 ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

This isn't displaying anything as the client space for `BasicEffect` is 0,0 at top-left, and 1-1 at bottom-right.
So I added this to `BasicEffect`:

```
_basicEffect = new BasicEffect( GraphicsDevice )
    {
        VertexColorEnabled = true
    } ;

_viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
    new Vector3( 0, 0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width ),
    Vector3.Zero,
    Vector3.Up
    ) ;

_projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(
    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,
    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height,
    .1f,
    GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width ) ;

_basicEffect.Projection = _projectionMatrix ;
_basicEffect.View = _viewMatrix ;
```

With this, the polygon is displayed but it's upside-down.  Also, when the position of the polygon changes (the user can drag the polygon around with the mouse), the polygon goes up when the user moves the mouse down!

I'm a bit thick (but trying to become less thick) when it comes to matrices and geometry.  Am I missing something?  I tried changing `Down` to `Up` in `CreateLookAt` but it still didn't draw correctly and now when the user mouses left, then polygon goes right!

Here's a screen-shot when drawing a polygon at 0,0:
[image]

The points on the white path are where the user clicked (and are drawn with SpriteBatch) and the yellow polygon is what's drawn by my method above.

Here's another screen-shot that show what happens when I move the polygon to 20,20:
[image]

The white path is drawn starting from 20,20, but the filled polygon is starting from 20,-20 and is drawn upside-down

I think this is a matrix issue between the matrix used by the `SpriteBatch` (to draw the white paths) and the matrix used by the `BasicEffect` (to draw the filled polygon).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

r2d2rigo's answer is *almost* correct. Here is the *correct* matrix code to set up a `BasicEffect` that matches `SpriteBatch` ([from Shawn Hargreaves' blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20150905162400/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)):

```
Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);

basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
basicEffect.View = Matrix.Identity;
basicEffect.Projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;
```

Note the half-pixel offset ([explanation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210725150811/http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/), [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d9/directly-mapping-texels-to-pixels)).

Comment: This multiplication "halfPixelOffset * projection" generates wrong results if the objective is to have the origin of the world in the Top-Left screen coordinate.

Comment: @EmirLima Yes, but usually that is ***not*** the objective. The objective in most cases - including the OP's case - is to line up with screen pixels in the same way that `SpriteBatch` does. See the links in my answer for more details (and note, of course, this applies to XNA and DirectX 9, but not to DirectX 10 and OpenGL).

Answer (score 3):

The matrix used in SpriteBatch is created with Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter:

```
Matrix ortho = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0.0f, yourWidth, yourHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

This way you will retain your world origin at the top left corner.